# Cinema4D: Animation question: How can you organise your different loops so they can be triggered one after the other?

Tags: animation, cinema4d

My interest is on animating characters on Cinema4D to then export into Unreal.

I'm trying to jump into the domain of animation after 8 years purely modelling and texturing.

What is the best way to organise your animations on the project so you can treat them all as part of the same rig?

Appreciate any help, I would look for answers if somebody can search some key points to explore.

Thanks!